# Why BlueTooth is activated after updating the iOS?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, software-update

I noticed something while updating the iOS. After finishing the updating, I always find that BlueTooth is on and activated.

Any idea why Apple is doing that?

Comment: Is the sequence - you turn off bluetooth, run the update, the device reboots and turns on bluetooth one time? Or are you saying that you can't turn off bluetooth at all or under some circumstances or that it turns itself back on later? (also, asking why apple does anything often gets closed as opinion-based. Is there something specific you have in mind and can refine that part or edit it to be less subjective?)

Comment: If it's turned off before the upgrade, it's turned on afterwards nevertheless.

Comment: @bmike My iPhone Bluetooth is always off. I don't use it at all.

Comment: @Chiron Apple ships devices with Bluetooth on, so perhaps they are returning some settings to default intentionally. It could also indicate that the settings are in a different place and they didn't migrate.

Comment: @Chiron AirDrop is the culprit here. Apple is trying to nudge you into using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple turns on Bluetooth because of iBeacon. Also, as previously mentioned by @Andrew Larsson, AirDrop is also a major reason. See here for more details: https://www.yahoo.com/tech/this-is-why-apple-enables-bluetooth-every-time-you-80079149965.html

A quick Google search reveals many interesting results: https://www.google.com/#q=why+is+bluetooth+enabled+after+updating